# How to empty Kendo editor using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I tried cleaning the values under the Kendo editor textarea with `$("#kedoEditorId").val('')`, but that doesn't work for me.

Is there any way to remove the value on the Kendo editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

// set value
editor.value("<p>new content</p>");

// get value
var htmlValue = editor.value();
```

Straight from the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor

Answer (score 1):

HTMl

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDescription)
```

JQuery

```
var editor = $("#JobDescription").data("kendoEditor");
if(ediot!=null)
{
  editor.value("new values");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use centrally For all those with data-role editor, Since kendo UI Editor appends data-role editor. For multiple text editors you can use.

```
var editor = $("textarea[data-role=\'editor\']").data("kendoEditor");
if(editor!=null){ editor.value(""); }
```

Comment: Ye. you should read the editor documentation. That is a What you See is what you get... so im fairly certain you are not using it corectly. there should be api documentation for clearing content.